# Luma theme deconfigured after installing sample data

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, frontend, css, luma-theme

Console error:

```
Refused to apply style from 'https://app.bartofilpc.test/media/styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

After installing Magento 2 Luma theme, some front-end configuration is missing.
Commands I've tried:

- Copying `vendor`and `composer.json` from another project
- `bin/magento setup:di:compile`
- `bin/magento sampledata:install` and `bin/magento setup:upgrade`
- Removing sampledata and installing again

[image]

Only thing that worked so far was reinstalling Magento.

P.S.: Had to reinstall the Magento store to work, because nothing worked so far (Aug 30, 2022).

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue recently and performed a config change:

- if you have access to the backend, go to `Store/Configuration/Advanced/Developer/Static Files Settings` and set the Field **Sign Static Files** to `No`
- if this is not possible, you can change the file `app/etc/env.php` and add the following at the end so that it appears like the screenshot below (dev should be a siblings to the node backend for instance)

  'dev' => [
  'static' => [
  'sign' => '0'
  ]
  ]

[image]

and then run `bin/magento set:upg`

Comment: The backend setting was already defined to `No` and the code is exactly as your screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the .htaccess file is existing in the pub/ and pub/media.

Comment: Both `.htaccess` files exist and were not modified.